# gRPC/Protobuf 3 syntax: what is the difference between rpc lines that end with semicolon vs '{}'?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I've seen two different ways of declaring an gRPC service using Protobuf v3. Some code has the [rpc line end with a semicolon](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#services) (such as the current proto3 documentation):

```
service SearchService {
  rpc Search (SearchRequest) returns (SearchResponse);
}
```

Other [code has the rpc line end with](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-common/blob/dacca2cd5e6191a0b221dea79b48c04a8ff6f9c2/protos/helloworld.proto#L39) `{}`:

```
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}
```

Both of these compile with the protoc v3.0.0-alpha-2 compiler and produce the same (go) code.

What is the difference between the two syntaxes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nothing, really; they are equivalent.

The `{}` syntax is used when there are options. If you don't specify any options, either syntax works (just like in C!).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have anything that shows options in use?

Comment: https://github.com/gengo/grpc-gateway makes use of them for REST→gRPC conversion (FYI: there in a PR to swap the annotations to those at https://github.com/google/googleapis/tree/master/google/api). Things like timeout could also eventually be specified with an option, but I don't think that those are defined yet.